# Placing dot element on round images on the same position

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way i can place a small dot div over some round images on the same position? The images are chosen by my website users so they don't have a fixed size. I want to place that dot just like in this photo below.

[image]

**Edit:** Sorry for not providing a code. Meanwhile, i have found a solution by targeting the img width by css. Here is my code for the working example:

```
<div class="img-box">
    <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
         <img width="100" height="100" alt="avatar" src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/28ad5c0c6da14d4abcaba545fd115289.png" class="user-avatar">
         <div class="user-status"></div>
   </a>
</div>

<div class="img-box">
    <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
         <img width="140" height="140" alt="avatar" src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/e1c7dec3eced491b8a16ac8d1103b5ea.png" class="user-avatar">
         <div class="user-status"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The css code:

```
.img-box{    
    margin: 40px;
}

a.avatar-link{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-box img.user-avatar{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
}

.user-status {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #ED0000;
}

.img-box img.user-avatar[width="140"] + .user-status{
   right: 16px;
   bottom: 15px;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/oabszsxe/2/)

Comment: Since you haven't provided any code or shown what you've tried, this is really a math question.  I'd suggest you look up 'Clock Face Math' and man of the tutorials are simple enough.  The dot can be placed through either CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: you only need css for the dot? Will the dots appear in all the case.. Please be clear and specific of what you are asking.  Provide a working example or some working reference. here is a link you can refer to on how ask question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough info. Meanwhile i have found the solution by css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `bottom` and `right` position as percentages, and then use `transform` to adjust the position according to the width / height of the red circle.

I created an element called `corner finder` to work out there percentage values (trial and error, I don't know what the maths would be).  This can be removed from your real code but helps demonstrate the process.  As the circle gets very big it goes very slightly off, but it's close.

```css
.img-box {
  margin: 40px;
}

.avatar-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14.8%;
  right: 14.8%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px); /* half width and height */
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar-link img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Can be removed, just for demonstration */
.corner-finder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14.8%;
  bottom: 14.8%;
  right: 14.8%;
  left: 14.8%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
    <div class="corner-finder"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="img-box">
  <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
    <div class="corner-finder"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="img-box">
  <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
    <div class="corner-finder"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""> 
  </a>
</div>

<div class="img-box">
  <a class="avatar-link" href="#">
    <div class="corner-finder"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great example but how about if i want to place to dot on the top right corner? i tried top: 14.8%; in place of the bottom for  .avatar-link::after , but it doesn't give me the same position. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you need to adjust the `transform`.  For top right you need to pull the image back up by half it's width, rather than push it down.  So as well as using `top: 14.8%` you'd change to `transform: translate(5px, -5px)`.  This is referring to `translateX` and `translateY`. https://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/kc7q10h4/4/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Any visual element should not be in your document.

Using CSS pseudo-element can achieve this visual effect.

HTML

```
<div class=circle></div>
```

SCSS

```
.circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Compiled CSS

```
.circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle::after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

If you need anything to be set dynamically try to alter the CSS property value using JavaScirpt.

CodePen sample (it's just a sample but you get the idea), https://codepen.io/li-xinyang/pen/qrWZgY

[image]

Comment: Your example needs a preprocessor I guess.

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: nice example but not useful as i can't edit the position of the dot based on the actual image size. For example if a user has an image width 190px, i need to have the style for the dot already created, as in my example above. It will probably work via jquery also but i believe is always better via css, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is a solution to accomplish this by using CSS only; however, some math need to be involved for sure.

Comment: Yeah,not that hard, just draw a line from the middle of the circle to the right bottom corner of the container and place the dot at the intersection of the right edge of the circle and that straight line.

Comment: Good to know that you have find the way to solve the issue.